# Is $\sum_{k\leqslant n} f'(k)f'(n-k) \asymp f'(n)f(n)$ when $f'$ is positive decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, asymptotics

> In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1060346/198706) of a question of mine, the user Homegrown Tomato
>   gave a nice argument that somewhat shows that
>
> $$\int_{\substack{t+s\leqslant x \\ t,s \geqslant 0}} f'(t)f'(s)dtds \asymp f(x)^2.$$
>
> I actually improved this statement (under the hypotheses of my
>   question) and concluded that in fact it's asymptotic to $C\cdot f(x)^2$ for some positive real constant $C$, but I'm not sure whether
>   that's beside the point of my actual question here or not.

I'm trying to estimate $\sum_{k\leqslant n} f'(k)f'(n-k)$ for $C^0$ decreasing $f'$, like $f'(x) = 1/\log{x}$, or $x^{-1},x^{-1/2},x^{-1/2}\log{x}$, etc. Unlike the case of $\sum_{k\leqslant n} f'(k)$, where to use the integral as an estimate is almost direct, I think something like

$$ \sum_{k\leqslant n} f'(k)f'(n-k) \overset{?}\sim \int_{0\leqslant t\leqslant n} f'(t)f'(n-t)dt \tag{1}$$

must be true, but I was not able to prove. Well, still on that thought, the integration here is occuring on part of the boundary of a triangle, the same triangle of the integration on my previous question that I quoted above! So I thought in to try to relate the two questions, using something like [Stokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) or [Reynolds' transport theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem), in order to get

$$\int_{0\leqslant t\leqslant x} f'(t)f'(x-t)dt \overset{?}\approx \frac{d}{dx}\int_{\substack{t+s\leqslant x \\ t,s \geqslant 0}} f'(t)f'(s)dtds \overset{?}\approx f'(x)f(x) \tag{2}.$$

So what I'm asking is: Is there a way to *formalize* **(1)** and **(2)**, or at least one of them? And if no (or even if yes), there is another way (an easier, preferably haha) to show the statement of the question? In the worst-case scenario, a counterexample will be welcome hahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning (1), you could use the [integral convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence): if $f'$ decreases not only towards $\infty$, but also towards $-\infty$, and $f'$ does not change sign, then $f'(\cdot) \space f'(n - \cdot)$ is a positive decreasing function of $\cdot$, which shows that $\sum \limits _{k=1} ^n = \sum \limits _{k=1} ^\infty - \sum \limits _{k=n+1} ^\infty$ behaves like $\int \limits _1 ^\infty - \int \limits _{n+1} ^\infty = \int \limits _1 ^n$.

Concerning (2), the integral in the middle term can be rewritten (using Fubini's theorem) as $\int \limits _0 ^x f'(s) \int \limits _0 ^{x-s} f'(t) \Bbb d t \Bbb d s$. Deriving with respect to $x$ one gets:

$$ f'(x) \int \limits _0 ^0 f'(t) \Bbb d t - f'(0) \int \limits _0 ^x f'(t) \Bbb d t \cdot 0'+ \int \limits _0 ^x f'(s) \Big( f'(x-s) - f'(0) \cdot 0'\Big) \Bbb d s = \int \limits _0 ^x f'(s) f'(x-s) \Bbb d s ,$$

i.e. you get precisely the first equality in (2) (and it is true equality, not asymptotic behaviour).

(A note on the derivation with respect to $x$ if you feel puzzled:

$$\frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d x} \int \limits _{f(x)} ^{g(x)} F(x,t) \Bbb d t = F \big(x, g(x) \big) g'(x) - F \big(x,f(x) \big) f'(x) + \int \limits _{f(x)} ^{g(x)} \frac {\partial F} {\partial x} (x, t) \Bbb d t ,$$

i.e. you derive according to a rule similar to Leibniz's product rule: first you derive the integral and keep the integrand unchanged, next you keep the integral but derive the integrand.)

Comment: Hmm, in the first case I was thinking in function defined on $(0,+\infty)$, like $1/\sqrt{x}$, I don't know if I can use that in this case, but I'll try! In (2) it seems pretty right, but I didn't verified yet (I have a little difficulty with derivation under integral sign haha), but what did you mean by $0'$?

Comment: @ChrisTáfula: Oh, $0'$ is an idiotic and pedantic way of reminding you that $0$ must be also derived - which, of course, gives you $0$, so those terms vanish too.