# Is $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k} \sim \frac{\log{n}}{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309847/is-sum-k-leqslant-n-fkfn-k-asymp-fnfn-when-f-is-positive-dec) some days ago, but in a more general form that perhaps turned it in a too uninteresting question, so I'm asking it again in a more friendly form.

It is true that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k} \sim \frac{\log{n}}{n} ?$$

I kind explained my intuition in the similar question that I linked above. Perhaps the only thing I tried so far was summation by parts, but it seems ineffective. I'm looking for a complete answer, but any kind of tips will be fairly welcome.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k} = \frac{1}{n}\biggl(\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{n-k}\biggr)$$

Comment: You have an explicit formula: $\frac{2}{n}(\Psi(n)+\gamma)$. The ratio $\frac{\Psi(n)}{\ln(n)}\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, that was clever, I can't believe I didn't see that before hahaha, now it follows directly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k} = 
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right) = 2\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}$$

where, $\displaystyle H_{n} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$ is the $n$-th Harmonic Number.

It is known that $H_n = \log n + \gamma +O(1/n)$.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate answer (though less exact), we can use the integral test of comparison. In general, if $f(x)$ is positive and decreasing, then 
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n f(k) \approx \int_1^n f(x) dx,$$
where we could be explicit about error bounds if we wanted to. Here, we are looking at
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{x(n - x)},$$
which is symmetric about the halfway point $x = n/2$. So although it only decreases for $x \in [1, n/2)$, by symmetry we can approximate the sum over the first half and then multiply by $2$. In other words,
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n \approx 2 \int_1^{n/2} \frac{1}{x(n - x)}dx = \frac{2}{n} \log n.$$

This is only the leading term of [sciona's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1330773/9754), but I'm always pleased when we can approach things using elementary tools I teach in my first or second semesters of calculus.

Comment: That was a nice answer! I think it kinda solves part of the problem in my previous question. Sciona's answer was very clean (a Book proof haha), but in some sense this answer says a little more if you're thinking in generalities.

Comment: Ehr, I have a question. Actually, you said that **for fixed $n$**, $1/x(n-x)$ is decreasing in $[1,n/2)$, so you can do something like
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{n/2} \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k} \leqslant \int_1^{n/2} \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{n-x} dx \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k},$$
but to conclude that it's in fact asymptotic, you need to show that $\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{n-1} \prec \sum_{k=2}^{n/2} \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k}$, so you can take the limit both sides and use sandwich rule. But is there a way to do that without solving the problem? The obvious _bound to the sum doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ChrisTáfula I would recommend instead to use the integral for bounds, since the integral is easier to understand. So then
$$ \int_1^{n/2} f(x) dx \leq \sum f(n) \leq f(1) + \int_1^{n/2} f(x) dx.$$
In doing things like proving the integral test for convergence, you can prove both of these things. This suggests the error term comes from $f(1)$, which looks like $\frac{1}{n}$. And so we would expect something like $\frac{2}{n}\log n + \frac{C}{n} + o(n)$ for some $C$. This accounts for the second term of sciona's answer.

Comment: Oh, now I see, this way you don't have to deal with any estimation to the sum. It took me a while to understand why adding $f(1)$ "sandwiches" the sum between the integrals, but now it makes perfect sense! Thanks for the explanation.